# command which takes in password as argument?

Tags: bash, sudo

Is there any bash command or technique through which we can enter in password alongwith the command which requires the password of superuser?
for e.g

```
sudo apt-get install kde <password>
```

I am actually using it to pass it in a c program which takes in bash command and prints out the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted it out finally

```
echo <mypassword> | sudo -S apt-get install <package name>
```

Comment: In general it is not recommended to work this way. Your password will be visible in your shell history and also in the `proc` filesystem. Other users might read it out.